# When using input in a function to return a number or string, it loops the input function twice

Tags: python

So I used an input in a function with an if statement to return a value, but it repeats the inputted statement/question before returning the value. When the input line comes up I enter 'x' and it repeats the inputted line a second time until 2 is returned and printed.

```
def code():
    x = input('type x ')
    if x == 'x':
        return 2


code()
print(code())
```

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to try, I'm completely clueless to why this is happening

Comment: You are calling the function twice... first time: `code()`. second time: `print(code())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you were calling the function twice. Try this

```
def code():
    x = input('type x ')
    if x == 'x':
        return 2


print(code())
```